# tinyMCE does not work in FormView with Edit mode in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, formview, edititemtemplate

Need your help,

I have implemented tinyMCE in my asp.net page with FormView, it is ok with Insert (InsertItemTemplate) and ReadOnly (ItemTemplate) mode, but the problem is when Edit (EditItemTemplate) mode, tinyMCE doesn't work and fire.

Below my asp.net page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
  mode: "textareas"
});
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanelmaster" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:FormView ID="FVWorkflowTaskEmailTemplate" runat="server" Width="100%" DefaultMode="Insert"
          EnableModelValidation="True">
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_BODY" EnableViewState="False" runat="server" CssClass="col-md-8 form-control "
                    TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="500" meta:resourcekey="txt_BODYResource2"></asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_BODY"  Text='<%# Bind("BODY") %>' runat="server"
                    CssClass="col-md-8 form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="500" 
        meta:resourcekey="txt_BODYResource1"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_BODY" EnableViewState="False" Enabled="False" Text='<%# Bind("BODY") %>'
                    runat="server" CssClass="col-md-8 form-control " TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="500"
                    meta:resourcekey="txt_BODYResource3"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

I use tinymce_4.1.3 that can be downloaded from http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your init-mode: is says textareas where it should be textarea.